# I need help Writing a sheets formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula

I have created a chart with constantly changing values. At the bottom, I have a formula combining each column of data into an easy to read format. At the top, I have a label for each column of data. I want to write a formula that finds the largest number in **"B10:F10"** and display the label for that column. I am not very experienced with Sheets, so any and all help is welcome and appreciated. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(B1:F1,0,MATCH(MAX(B10:F10),B10:F10,0))`

`MAX(B10:F10)` will find out the maximum of the numbers

`MATCH(MAX(B10:F10),B10:F10,0)` will give you the position of the maximum number

`INDEX(B1:F1,0,MATCH(MAX(B10:F10),B10:F10,0))` with starting point as B1, it will move the number of columns corresponding to the maximum number and give you the heading related to it.

Comment: please upvote and mark as correct answer, if this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6, 1+MATCH(MAX(B10:F10), B10:F10, 0))), MAX(B10:F10)}
```

[image]